# It's possible to detect a many-to-many relationship on a rlinq file?

Tags: sql, telerik

I am working on a project manually mapping entities from a SQL db. My primary source of information about columns, keys, relationships, and others is the rlinq generate by Telerik from the db.
I wonder if it's possible to detect a many-to-many relationship based on only in this file.